# Passing fixed size array of bytes32[] between two contracts

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, arrays

I am using two contracts where one calls a function of the other:

```
contract con1 {
    bytes32[5] data;

    function con1(){
    }

    function addData(bytes32[5] a) { //fills the array
    }   

    function getData() public constant returns(bytes32[5]){  //retrieve array
        return (data);
    }
}
```

The next contract calls `getData` from the above contract after it has been filled using `addData`:

```
contract con2 {
    function con2(){
    }

    function try(address con1Contract){
        con1 b = con1(con1Contract);
        bytes32[5] y = b.getData();
    }
  ....
}
```

Since in Solidity we cannot pass dynamic sized arrays, I fixed the size of the array. However, I still get the following error:

```
TypeError: Type bytes32[5] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32[5] storage pointer.
bytes32[5] y = b.getData();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: My question is not a duplicate. The other question is trying to receive the return call in a dynamic size array.

Comment: It is. The same issue is encountered and an answer is given in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your "y" array property of the contract

```
 contract con1 {
    bytes32[5] data;

    function con1(){
    }

    function addData(bytes32[5] a) { //fills the array
    }   

    function getData() public constant returns(bytes32[5]){  //retrieve array
        return (data);
    }
}

contract con2 {
    bytes32[5] y;
    function con2(){
    }

    function trys(address con1Contract){
        con1 b = con1(con1Contract);
         y = b.getData();
    }
}
```

It works for me.